# Regex that allows 3-20 digits and must end with 00

Tags: regex

I have a regex `".*00$"` which restricts that the input must be ending with 00. How can I improve this to add a max length of 20 also. So:

100 => valid,

00 = > invalid,

12345678900 => valid,

111111111111111111100 = > 21 digits - invalid.

Comment: by "max length of 20" do you mean "max value of 20"?

Comment: sorry, i mean, max length of 20 digits

Comment: so 21 digits is not valid

Comment: Is "000" a valid number? Or "0000"? Or also "0100"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your title and short description this should probably work for you:

```
^[0-9]{1,18}00$
```

This will allow 3-20 digits in input that ends with `00`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
^[1-9][0-9]{0,17}00$
```

The first [] will ensure it doesn't start by 0.

Answer (score 1):

This can be expressed almost literally as

```
/^[0-9]{1,18}00$/
```

20 digits, the last two being zeros.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{}` to specify a range of characters, so

```
".{1,18}00"
```

would allow any 1-18 characters followed by `00`.  If you want to restrict it further, you could use

```
"[1-9][0-9]{0,17}00"
```

so that you ensure the first number is not 0, followed by 0-17 numbers and finally `00`.